# PHP setcookie() Issues

Tags: php, html, mysql, setcookie

I have a php file:

```
<?php 
$username = $_POST["username"];

if((!$username) || (!$_POST["password"])){
    header("Location:http://localhost/login.html");
    exit;
}

$db_name = "muzak";
$tblname = "auth_users";
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***username***", "***password***", $db_name) or die("Couldn't connect to database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE username = '$username' AND password= password('$_POST[password]')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$numHits = mysqli_num_rows($result);
var_dump($numHits);//equal to one

if($numHits > 0){
    $cookie_name = "auth";
    $cookie_value = "ok";
    $cookie_expire = "0";
    $cookie_domain = "127.0.0.1";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expire, "/" , $cookie_domain, 0);

    $display = "<li><a href=\"secret_areaA.php\">Secret Area A</a></li>
                <li><a href=\"secret_areaB.php\">Secret Area B</a>  </li>";
}else{
    header("Location:http://localhost/login.html");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Secret Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $display;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Which takes input from an html file and asks a database for confirmation. The HTML part works fine, but when I try to check for the presence of the cookie in the secret_areaA.php file . . .

```
<?php 
if($_COOKIE["auth"] == "ok"){
    $msg = "<p><Welcome to the first secret area!<p>";
}else{
    die("Cookie wasn't valid");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Secret Area A
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $msg;?>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error: Notice: Undefined index: auth in C:\xampp\htdocs\secret_areaA.php on line 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A cookiedomain can't be an ip. It has to be an actual fully qualified domain name. So `localhost` would be allowed, but `127.0.0.1` wouldn't.

Comment: I think that in your secret_areaA.php file you need to add a PHP include for the first file, since that is where your variable of `auth` is declared.

Comment: You should not be storing any sort of authentication indicator directly in cookies.  This is quite easily forged to get around your security.  Consider using session for this.

Comment: **Note:** Doing authentication this way is easily hackable by a user who knows how to use the web inspector or firebug. It's highly insecure.

Comment: I wasn't really planning on using this for a live website. However, all these comments and answers have been immensely helpful. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Cookie `expire` set to `0` lets the cookie expire right after it got set. So it will never be present.

The time you will set there must be `time() + $seconds`, not just `$seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the cookie is set (exists) using `isset()`, before you try to compare the value. This way, if the cookie hasn't been set, we don't try to access a part of the `$_COOKIE` array that can't exist (`['auth']`).

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['auth'] ) && $_COOKIE['auth'] == 'ok' ){
} else {
}
```

Comment: -1. This doesn't answer why the Cookie is never set. Just how to avoid the error displaying.

Comment: Why -1? The question doesn't ask about the cookie being set, it asks why the error is given. This answer solves the error.

Comment: @BenM The error should still be handled, though. This doesn't deserve a negative score.

Comment: I never doubted that the error shouldn't be handled. But this answer doesn't address the real issue, of why `$_COOKIE['auth']` isn't set; ergo, it's an incomplete answer IMHO.